# Garage door hard-wired wall button doesn't work after adding wireless controller dongle in parallel

Tags: home-automation

I have a standard garage door controller (Chamberlain HD900D) with a wired button inside the garage, and wireless clickers that all work properly.

I purchased a [GoControl/Linear GD00Z-4 ZWave Garage Door Opener](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00M75TEIU) so that I can control the garage with some automation.

The hard-wired wall button has two wires that run to the Garage Door opener.  The ZWave controller also has two wires that run to the Garage Door opener.  The installation manual says that the ZWave controller wires should just go into the exact same place as the wall-button wires.  So after installing I end up with something like this:

[image: Simplified circuit diagram]

When everything is wired up, the ZWave controller and the wireless clickers can open and close the door without issue.  However the wall button no longer functions.  Removing either one of the wires running to the ZWav controller fixes the issues.  I removed and re-added the wire multiple times and everything was connected using wire nuts.  Either connected on their own work, so it's only when they're BOTH connected that the wall switch doesn't work.

The symbols in the diagram are simplified.  I don't know whether or not the switches are open or closed at rest.  What could possibly cause the wall switch to fail in this configuration?

Comment: door remote switches are usually open (not conducting) at rest, so that part of the drawing is good.

Comment: does the door start immediately when you disconnect the remote receiver, or do you need to disconnect it and then press the button?  try swapping the two wires from the remote reveiver. check that the power supply to the remote receiver is operating.

Comment: Sure looks like voltage sag caused by the Z-Wave presenting too little impedance even in the "off" state.

Comment: @Jasen - I need to disconnect the ZWave switch and then I cam use the wall switch as normal.  I will try swapping the wires but the ZWave switch has worked fine through all previous tests.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - That's reasonable.  How would I go about fixing this?  Could I put a resistor inline with anything.  Throw a capacitor across the inputs?

Comment: @BenRandall In theory, putting a resistor inline (on the hot side! never on the return) with the Z-Wave will at least test my theory.  But it might also present too much impedance when the ZWave is "on" .  I'm guessing these lines are all DC voltage (but check the manual or schematics), so perhaps start by measuring the voltages when everything's "off" and then with ZWave disconnected, etc.

Comment: please clarify what happens when you disconnect the zwave,  does the door immediaely start moving or not, you will have to do this with the power turned on, the voltages on the terminals involved are not hazardous.